# spring MVC html5video

Tags: html, spring-mvc, html5-video

I am trying to run below as JSP from within Spring Web MVC application on my localhost.

Video is playing but SEEK is not working, by clicking on SEEK to have it ahead, it again goes back to original place.

Please help, below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>

<video controls preload="true" > 
  <source src="/path/to/assets/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: The answer to this question helped in this.

 <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634603/how-do-i-return-a-video-with-spring-mvc-so-that-it-can-be-navigated-using-the-ht>